# How to Draw Lines in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating One Cross Platform Application in Xamarin Forms and try to draw lines from 10 to -10 using below code. But the problem is lines are drawn from 10 to 0 only. Why this is happening I don't have any Idea.

```
int margin = 20;
int steps = 20;

float start = margin;
float end = width - margin;

float dHeigth = heigth - (margin * 4);
float hStep = dHeigth / Convert.ToSingle(steps);

float textMargin = 30;

// draw the line
for (int i = 10; i >= -10; i--)
{
    float xpoint = i * hStep + margin;

    if (i.IsOdd())
    {
        canvas.DrawLine(start + textMargin, xpoint, end, xpoint, LineWhitePaint);
    }
    else
    {
        decimal dText = 0;
        canvas.DrawLine(start + textMargin, xpoint, end, xpoint, LineGreyPaint);
        if (i < 0)
            dText = i;
        else
            dText = (10 - i);
        string txt = dText.ToString();

        canvas.DrawText(txt, start + margin, xpoint + 15, TextStyleFillPaintX);
    }
}
```

I am attaching screen shot of that

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: have you tried debugging this and checking the dimensions

Comment: Yes, I just want to display text in descending order.

Comment: Have you debugged this and put a break point on?

Comment: Actually I am displaying Text using "dText = (10 - i);" this line, but when I become -1 it adds value in 10 i.e. It becomes 11. How can I display -1 instead of that?

Comment: Yes, I am using "SKCanvas"

Comment: No I have change code From if (i < 0)
            dText = i;
        else
            dText = (10 - i); to only dText = 0-i; then only display from -10 to 0.

Comment: calling the y coordinate xpoint. that is some subtle trolling for anyone who ends up maintaining this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the positive lines, you are drawing `10 - i`, which yields `0` for the first iteration, `2` for the third and so on. Regarding this, you can see, that you are beginning to draw the lines from the middle of the canvas. The tenth iteration will draw the topmost line (the one with the 10). Further lines *are* drawn, but not on the screen.

You can see this, too, when you are writing `xPoint` to the debug output. As `i` gets negative, `xPoint` will, too. To fix this, you'll have to offset `xPoint` to always draw on screen

```
float xpoint = i * hStep + margin + steps / 2 * hStep;
```

Alternatively, you could loop from 20 to 0 and change how the text is generated.

```
for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var xPoint = i * hStep + margin;

    // ...

    var displayedText = GetDisplayedText(i, steps);

    // ...
}

string GetDisplayedText(int i, int steps)
{
    var displayedValue = i > steps / 2 
        ? steps - i
        : -i - steps / 2; // I think this should be the formula
    return displayedValue.ToString();
}
```

**Remarks:** It would even better to encapsulate the concept of the lines, to separate their calculation from draawing them. You could create a factory that generates the correct line based on the index and the number of steps and then only iterate over the `Line` objects, and draw them by passing the canvas. This would make your code way cleaner and neater.

**UPDATE**

Since we have been able to clarify the requirements, I will give another shot.

First of all, I'd define methods to transform graph coordinates to canvas coordinates

```
private SKPoint ToCanvasCoordinates(SKPoint graphCoordinates)
{
    var x = Margin + TextMargin + (_canvas.Width - 2*Margin - TextMargin)*graphCoordinates.X;
    var y = (MaxY - graphCoordinates.Y)*(_canvas.Height - 2 * Margin)/(MaxY - MinY) + Margin;

    return new SKPoint(x,y);
}

private SKPoint GetLegendCoordinates(int i)
{
    var x = Margin;
    var y = (MaxY - graphCoordinates.Y)*(_canvas.Height - 2 * Margin)/(MaxY - MinY) + Margin + 15;

    return new SKPoint(x,y);
}
```

`_canvas` is a private member field in this case, `Margin`, `MaxY` and `MinY` are properties. I've assumed the min of `x` being 0 and the max bein 1.

Now you can draw your lines like

```
for(int i = -1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var lineStart = ToCanvasCoordinates(new SKPoint(0, i));
    var lineEnd = ToCanvasCoordinates(new SKPoint(1, i));

    canvas.DrawLine(lineStart, lineEnd, LineGreyPaint);

    var textPosition = GetLegendCoordinates(i);

    canvas.DrawText(i.ToString(), textPosition, TextStyleFillPaintX);
}
```

Furthermore, if you'd like to draw a line between two of the grid lines, you can use the following methods

```
private void DrawDataLine(SKPoint start, SKPoint end, SKPaint paint)
{
    var startTransformed = ToCanvasCoordinates(start);
    var endTransformed = ToCanvasCoordinates(end);

    _canvas.DrawLine(startTransformed, endTransformed, paint);
}

private void DrawData(SKPaint paint)
{
    for(int i=1; i<_data.Length; i++)
    {
        DrawDataLine(new SKPoint(data[i-1].X, data[i-1].Y), new SKPoint(data[i].X, data[i].Y)); // given that the objects in _data have the properties X and Y
    }
}
```

Comment: It displays from -20 to 0

Comment: Then you'll have to adapt the method that calculates the displaey number. But it does display all lines?

Comment: Yes, It displays all lines

Comment: Actually, I just want to show from 10 to -1 text, from Top to bottom and display dynamic graph lines connecting to dots depends on data. How's that possible?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar You'd like to display 12 lines, topmost one with the caption 10, second with the caption 9 and so on? Did I get you right?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Please see my edit, if that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but now requirement is change and just want to display +10 to -10 and using your "float xpoint = i * hStep + margin + steps / 2 * hStep;" this code, it works as Expected.